# How to change all input value by select an option

Tags: javascript, html

**How to change all input value by select an option. Please help me.**

```js
function getValue(selectObject) {
        var someValue = selectObject.value;
        document.getElementById("msn_v").value = someValue;
    }
```

```html
<select class="outofstockselectswitch" onchange="getValue(this)">
   <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>



<form>
    <input id="msn_v" name="p_name" >
    <input id="msn_v" name="p_name" >
    <input id="msn_v" name="p_name" >
    <input id="msn_v" name="p_name" >
</form>
```

**This code is working for first inputs only. But i need to change all input value. **

Comment: Elements must have a *unique* id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id attribute in HTML is unique. You should rather use class , then using document.getElementsByClassName , you can set the inputs.

```js
function getValue(selectObject) {
        var someValue = selectObject.value;
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("msn_v"); 
        
        for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
          inputs[i].value = someValue;
        }
    }
```

```html
<select class="outofstockselectswitch" onchange="getValue(this)">
   <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>



<form>
    <input class="msn_v" name="p_name" >
    <input class="msn_v" name="p_name" >
    <input class="msn_v" name="p_name" >
    <input class="msn_v" name="p_name" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const v_brand = document.querySelector("#v_brand");
const p_names = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='p_name']");


const p_names_updater = () => p_names.forEach(input => input.value = v_brand.value);

v_brand.addEventListener("change", p_names_updater);

p_names_updater();
```

```html
<select id="v_brand">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>



<form>
  <input name="p_name">
  <input name="p_name">
  <input name="p_name">
  <input name="p_name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```js
document.getElementById("msn_v").value = someValue;
```

To this:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('[name=p_name]')].forEach(elem => elem.value = someValue);
```